# VBA change dot to comma

Tags: excel, vba

```
        Range("T:T").Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Hello everyone, I use Record Macro to get this code. When I do it manually the dot will change to comma. But when I use the macro to do it, the dot will not change to comma. I think this might be some bugs...How do I do this alternative? I tried for loop to do this but the speed is too slow, I have many row of data.

Comment: This must work . Working for me. You are making mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Does your range same for all the time? Are you trying for range `T:T` or for different range.

Comment: I try for T:T and T:U , but both also not work.

Comment: I also try for using columns but also not work

Comment: Are the `.` that you want to replace real dots or are they part of  a numeric value?

Comment: The dot is the separator for number, for example 4000.00 . I want to change it to 4000,00

Comment: If the values in your cell are already numbers, you just need to change the format of the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the code you provided should work. However if the dots you are trying to replace are part of a numeric value then you'll need to change your **Decimal Separator** settings:

1. Navigate to **File** > **Options**
2. Click the **Advanced** sub-menu on the left-hand side of the **Excel Options** dialog
3. Uncheck the **Use system separators** checkbox
4. Then change the **Decimal separator** field from `.` to `,`

[Decimal Separator option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs9jB.png)

Comment: Should also mention that this change won't be restricted to range `T:T` but will apply to **all** worksheets